# Drupal - Why do I keep getting error message "Table variable already exists." when trying to setup drupal on my XAMPP localhost

Tags: php, drupal

I am using PHPMyAdmin 4.2.11 and Drupal 7.37

I created a database in PHPMyAdmin called `drupaldatabase` and now I'm trying to add it on Drupal using database name: `drupaldatabase` and username `root` with no password.

If you need any more info let me know.

Comment: **If you need any more info let me know** sure some code would be nice to look at

Comment: `“Table variable already exists.”` That sounds like you trying to use a table that allready has some content and drupal can't overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your database is empty by killing it

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE drupaldatabase;
```

And create database again:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE drupaldatabase;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL configuration:

```
autocommit = on
```